# Facebook "Recommend" button share-able

Tags: facebook, url, button, share

I am trying to share the facebook's "Recommend" button for my page. So I want to create a post, or send a direct link to my friends in order to recommend my page.
Would that be possible?
I don't want to ask them to go to my page and click the "Recommend" button, but give them a direct link to open the recommendation box, as below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible see URL;

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/recommendations

Comment: hmm, and do you believe there's really no way around it? :)

Comment: I would take a look for you on the full facebook developer page and eventually some forums.

Comment: Would you please accept my answer because there is no way round it.